# What does Arrow in mysql require

Tags: mysql

It is my first times creating a database in mysql and i performed the following operations

```
CREATE DATABASE logs
USE logs
CREATE TABLE FROM_DHCP(host varchar(35))
```

the result is an arrow which has frustrated me the whole  morning, what does this arrow want me to do, i know it requires input but all i want to do for now is to create the table then display the table . ny help would be truly be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add a closing ; (semicolon) to each mysql command. In this case:

```
CREATE DATABASE logs;
USE logs;
CREATE TABLE FROM_DHCP(host varchar(35));
```

please note that even though the table will be created, you probably want to add a Primary Key to your table.

PS: only exception to the semicolon rule is the USE statement where you can omit it.